# Invalid method Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Login::__ [] []

Tags: magento2

I keep getting this error when ever i navigate to the login page after i installed my module:

> Invalid method Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Login::__ [] []

I don't know what's causing it so i'll link the module github project: https://github.com/CallumBrankin/Magento2-Inchoo-Social-Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This line](https://github.com/CallumBrankin/Magento2-Inchoo-Social-Plugin/blob/master/app/code/Inchoo/SocialConnect/Block/Login.php#L128) is the problem.

```
$this->registry->register('inchoo_socialconnect_button_text', $this->__('Login'));
```

should be

```
$this->registry->register('inchoo_socialconnect_button_text', __('Login'));
```

Maybe you should open an issue in their repo or even a PR.

Comment: It's my repo, it's a converted 1.9 module

Comment: Solved the problem, now i'm getting "Invalid method Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Login::_getColSet"